# Java language detection with langdetect - how to load profiles?

Tags: java, jar, classpath, language-detection

I'm trying to use a Java library called `langdetect` hosted [here](http://code.google.com/p/language-detection/). It couldn't be easier to use:

```
Detector detector;
String langDetected = "";
try {
    String path = "C:/Users/myUser/Desktop/jars/langdetect/profiles";
    DetectorFactory.loadProfile(path);
    detector = DetectorFactory.create();
    detector.append(text);
    langDetected = detector.detect();
} 
catch (LangDetectException e) {
    throw e;
}

return langDetected;
```

**Except** with respect to the `DetectFactory.loadProfile` method. This library works great when I pass it an absolute file path, but ultimately I think I need to package my code and `langdetect`'s companion `profiles` directory inside the same JAR file:

```
myapp.jar/
    META-INF/
    langdetect/
        profiles/
            af
            bn
            en
            ...etc.
    com/
        me/
            myorg/
                LangDetectAdaptor --> is what actually uses the code above
```

I will make sure that the `LangDetectAdaptor` which is located inside `myapp.jar` is supplied with both the `langdetect.jar` and `jsonic.jar` dependencies it needs for `langdetect` to work at runtime. However I'm confused as to what I need to pass in to `DetectFactory.loadProfile` in order to work:

- The `langdetect` JAR ships with the `profiles` directory, but you need to initialize it from inside your JAR. So do I copy the `profiles` directory and put it inside my JAR (like I prescribe above), or is there a way to keep it inside `langdetect.jar` but access it from inside my code?

Thanks in advance for any help here!

**Edit** : I think the problem here is that `langdetect` *ships* with this `profiles` directory, but then wants you to initialize it from inside your JAR. The API would probably benefit from being changed a little bit to just consider `profiles` its own configuration, and to then provide methods like `DetectFactory.loadProfiles().except("fr")` in the event that you don't want it to initialize French, etc. But this still doesn't solve my problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the library only accepts files.  You can either change the code and try submitting the changes upstream.  Or write your resource to a temp file and get it to load that.

Comment: Thanks @vickirk (+1) - are you saying I have to specify every single language I want to load (I don't think that's the case). Can you be more specific and give a concrete code example? For instance what do you mean by "*submit the changes upstream*", or "*write your resource to a temp file*"? What resource?! Thanks again!

Comment: In fact I know this isnt the case because my code snippet above (which uses the abs file path to the `profiles` directory) works like a charm...

Comment: The library expects a String to a directory path or an actual File for the directory.  It therefore can not get resources out of a jar.  You would have to write the files to a directory on the file system

Answer (score 7):

I have the same problem. You can load the profiles from the LangDetect jar using [JarUrlConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/JarURLConnection.html)  and [JarEntry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarEntry.html). Note in this example I am using Java 7 resource management.

```
    String dirname = "profiles/";
    Enumeration<URL> en = Detector.class.getClassLoader().getResources(
            dirname);
    List<String> profiles = new ArrayList<>();
    if (en.hasMoreElements()) {
        URL url = en.nextElement();
        JarURLConnection urlcon = (JarURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        try (JarFile jar = urlcon.getJarFile();) {
            Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = jar.entries();
            while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
                String entry = entries.nextElement().getName();
                if (entry.startsWith(dirname)) {
                    try (InputStream in = Detector.class.getClassLoader()
                            .getResourceAsStream(entry);) {
                        profiles.add(IOUtils.toString(in));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    DetectorFactory.loadProfile(profiles);
    Detector detector = DetectorFactory.create();
    detector.append(text);
    String langDetected = detector.detect();
    System.out.println(langDetected);
```

Comment: Super ! But i notice there are 2 profiles directories ? profiles/ and profiles.sm/

Comment: Hi Albert, I don't know what the difference is between the two directories - you would need to add nakatani.shuyo who is responsible for langdetect? I don't think you can load both at the same time, because they overlap. If you need profiles.sm, just change the directory. We are mainly working with Mandarin, they are only in profiles, not profiles.sm, hence the code above.

Comment: I got replies from Shuyo, stating that profiles.sm is language profiles for short messages i.e. twitter. I confidently assume 'sm' means 'short messages'. Hope this helps.

Comment: The suggested solution is nice, but works only if the profiles directory is contained in the jar file. This is not the case if you use the jar file from the project's website.

Comment: Hi Jolo -  I am getting the jar via Maven or SBT as described here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.cybozu.labs/langdetect/1.1-20120112

Comment: com.cybozu.labs.langdetect.LangDetectException: Need more than 2 profiles
07-14 17:15:24.840 14147-14147/ W/System.err:     at com.cybozu.labs.langdetect.DetectorFactory.loadProfile(DetectorFactory.java:104)
07-14 17:15:24.840 14147-14147/ W/System.err:     at com.views.MainActivity$override.loadLibrary(MainActivity.java:114)
07-14 17:15:24.840 14147-14147/ W/System.err:     at com.views.MainActivity$override.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)

Answer (score 4):

Since no maven-support was available, and the mechanism to load profiles was not perfect (since you you need to define files instead of resources), I created a fork which solves that problem:

https://github.com/galan/language-detector

I mailed the original author, so he can fork/maintain the changes, but no luck - seems the project is abandoned.

Here is an example of how to use it now (own profiles can be written where necessary):

```
DetectorFactory.loadProfile(new DefaultProfile()); // SmProfile is also available
Detector detector = DetectorFactory.create();
detector.append(input);
String result = detector.detect();
// maybe work with detector.getProbabilities()
```

I don't like the static approach the DetectorFactory uses, but I won't rewrite the full project, you have to create your own fork/pull request :)

Comment: @arnt There is no repository for the project yet. You have to install it by yourself using `mvn install`, that's all.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Method DetectorFactory.LoadProfile(String) is not applicable ofr the arguments DefaultProfile.

Answer (score 2):

The solution provided by Mark Butler is still valid and solved my problem, but the dirname needs to be updated as the jar content has changed.
The problem has been reported by Deepak but I have insufficient reputation to reply in comments. Here you are the two declarations you need.

In order to load short profiles:

```
String dirname = "profiles/shorttext/";
```

In order to load long profiles:

```
String dirname = "profiles/longtext/";
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting the working dir for me fixed the problem.

```
 String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
 DetectorFactory.loadProfile(workingDir+"/profiles/");
```